# TitleForHeaderInSection not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

This app is just for research and learning purposes. I'm new to developing, so there is nothing fancy about that, really.

It should display a TableView with some contacts, which are split into two different categories: Recent & Friends

However, when I try to return those to be displayed as a header (everything else worked just as I intended it to) with the TitleForHeaderInSection function, only one gets displayed eventually. (I used a switch function, so for that matter only case 0 is displaying).

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2 // Recent & Friends

}
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    switch section {

    case 0: return "RECENT"

    case 1: return "FRIENDS"

    default: break

    }

    return String(section)
}
```

[image]

As seen in the screenshot above, in the app only one of the two cases gets returned and I am genuinely struggling to figure out why.

Comment: It's working for me, how are you creating your header ?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    switch section {

    case 0: return "RECENT"

    case 1: return "FRIENDS"

    default: break

    }

    return String(section)
}

Answer (score 0):

is it showing sections or sections are missing, not just heading ?if sections are missing then you need to select tableview style grouped in storyboard

Comment: It is just showing one section from the switch statement, which is the problem, as I want two. (See screenshot in the main post)...

Answer (score 0):

Its because you dint implement these delegates :(1) `viewforHeaderInSection` (2)`heightForHeaderInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

   //Create label which you want to show on each section header and return it 

}
```

Also use `heightForHeaderInsection` method .

Hope this help to solve your issue